# Are Adam Jensen and the Denton brothers related?

Tags: video-games, deus-ex

In Deus Ex Human Revolution Adam Jensen is revealed to be special in that his body naturally accepts augmentations with zero rejection. In the original Deus Ex both Paul and JC Denton are also unique in their body's natural acceptance of their augmentations.

Is this similarity a simple coincidence and this fact is used only to help the player feel their character is special, or is there supposed to be a familial link between Jensen and the Dentons that explains this unique character trait?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though never stated explicitly, the [Acquaintances Forgotten](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Acquaintances_Forgotten) side quest, combined with the revelations concerning Megan Reed's research, and in particular, the cutscene following the end credits ([The D Project](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/The_D_Project)), strongly imply that Megan uses her research into Adam's tolerance to augmentations at VersaLife, working for Bob Page as part of the team that 'created' the Denton Brothers and nano-augmentation technology.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Paul Denton was born 2018, waaaaay before Megan discovered about Adam. What is even more important is that it is a main plot element of the first Deus Ex, that it's not just the Dentons or their clones that can tolerate augmentations, but a small number of the population.

Here is something from the bible:

The Illuminati -- then in power, though no one knew it -- had done a great, secret census between 1940 and 1965, tracking everyone who received a small pox vaccine. From this they were able to build a database of the genetic codes of nearly all citizens of the United States and much of the rest of the world.

The conspirators' agents, posing as nurses and doctors, in pediatricians' offices and elementary schools across the nation, used the smallpox census data, to keep track of high potential candidates. The specialists in charge of the project were updated regularly on the progress of potential candidates. All the conspirators had to do was wait. Ma and Pa Denton -- two such potential candidates -- fell in love (perhaps even with some help from the conspirators!) and produced young Paul under the watchful, albeit covert eye of Majestic 12 operatives who played the parts of friends, family doctors, neighbors, school teachers and so on...

Answer (score -2):

I know this game is old and the topic is old, but the question still remains a valid point, given the recent mankind divided story kinda failed to elaborate on it any further...

As far as I remember and thought back in 2002 (when I first played Deus ex, GOTY), Paul is the older brother with JC, being either a clone of Paul or a step sibling even? (or possibly just a younger brother).

But when we look at Task force 29 and UNATCO, they kinda seem to be one and the same, just Tf29 seems to be the initial offering of UNATCO, just kinda low key, half arsed, under funded, secretive etc. 
Where as UNATCO, seems to be a massive world wide force akin to the FBI, but with far more manpower and resources to run an effective anti terror operation.

Now I may be wrong on my ideas, but I think they have some merit and could be plausible theories. But unless they kill off Adam, were will he fit into any sequel/remake of the original?
Could he be Paul's brother? Maybe his uncle?

On a side note, just a few of my grievances with the original and prequels;

How come they never introduced agents Gunther or Anna in the prequels? they were clearly physical Aug era same as Adam (maybe slightly later even), but still around in the prequel timeline.
I mean we get to see and hear of Manderly, Tracer tongs father, so why not more tie ins from original Deus ex characters, given Mankind divided is supposed to be set just before Deus ex.

I always found it odd they never really showed how JC traveled most the time, kinda works in any sequel or remakes favor though, as they now have artistic license to decide on it them self.

One thing that I hate about the prequels though with a passion, the lack of weapons compared to the original, I mean how can you remove basic hand weapons such as knifes etc, ok it looks way cooler with his integrated aug weapons, but really? Do you expect us to do the same variation of lethal/non all game just because you cba to add in a variety of melee weapons? I mean just something as simple as being able to pickup debris to toss as a distraction is missing... (unless you class a flying bucket or printer etc as distraction, imo a big 
"here I am and this is where I threw it from" in a real life scenario).

If anyone has further ideas would be nice to read them.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm not too familiar with this game, so it's hard for me to judge the merits and demerits of your answer here, but you seem to be saying an awful lot and there's an awful lot of your personal feelings here "On a side note, just a few of my grievances with the original and prequels". One thing that's very important to learn about this site is that it's not a forum, but a Q&A site, questions at the top, answers to that question (ideally fully-supported with quotes/references/etc.) at the bottom, and that's kind of it for this part of the site really

Comment: We do have a chat room for conversations, and there's a blog, but in the Q&A site, you're not participating in a discussion, or starting or adding to a comment thread, you're just answering the question at the top