# Is there a relationship between the protagonists of the Deus Ex games?

Tags: deus-ex

In the original Deus Ex, the protagonist is named "JC Denton". In its sequel, set twenty years later, the protagonist is named "Alex D". In the latest two games (Human Revolution & Mankind Divided), set thirty years before the original, the name of the protagonist is "Adam Jensen". All three protagonists bear a physical resemblance, being Caucasian men with similar builds, hair colors and appearances.

The Deus Ex franchise is tied together by various characters that appear throughout its timeline, but **is there any evidence of a familial relationship between the three protagonists listed above?**

Comment: I know part of this question has already been covered [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16028/38235), but that question admittedly doesn't cover Invisible War.  Which if I understand correctly, a lot of people try to forget.

Comment: @Radhil - good catch, hadn't seen that one. The accepted answer for that question seems a little speculative to me, but if no one has an answer after a couple of days I'll close this one. And if Adam Jensen's DNA was used to create the immune system bit for Denton, as the answer suggests, that would still qualify as a relationship in my book.

Comment: "Caucasian men" - the original has a choice of race (or at least skin tone), and IW has a choice of gender.

Comment: @OrangeDog - yes, but the canon appearance of each protagonist is a white Caucasian male with dark hair.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spoilers for the end of Deus Ex:

> The "D" in "Alex D" stands for Denton. Like JC, Alex is cloned from Paul and grown in a vat in Area 51. In Deus Ex you find the vat labelled "Alex Denton" towards the end of the game.

And Human Revolution:

> Megan is recruited to work on the nano-augmentation project and presumably uses her research on Adam's unique augmentation compatibility to work on the design of Paul and JC (though Paul was already born by this point).